# ContextCompat.GetDrawable is not giving expected result in android (Xamarin)

Tags: android, xamarin.android, android-drawable, android-context

As I am getting `Oval` result from my server and I set `Oval.png` in my Drawable folder. But When I set it Runtime The output throw `NoResource Found`. The below way I am setting the Image to my ImageView.

**Code :**

```
var drawName = item.Shape;
var resId = ContextCompat.GetDrawable(context,context.Resources.GetIdentifier(drawName, "drawable", context.PackageName));

vh.dImage.SetImageDrawable(resId);
```

**Or :**  if I can set Image then also that not work. the code is below

```
var drawName = item.Shape;
var resId = context.Resources.GetIdentifier(drawName, "drawable", context.PackageName);

vh.dImage.SetImageResource(resId);
```

I am using upper code in `RecycleView.Adapter`

Answer (score 0):

Drawable Resource files should be lowercase.  If not, you will experience various issues, such as GetIdentifier() always returning zero.